# How to export full Chrome history including synced data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-headless

Chrome stores its history in a SQLite database in this directory: `<CHROME_PROFILE_DIR>/History`.

However, this file does not include any URLs visited on other devices, even after a full sync.

Is there a way to automate the export of the full history, including URLs visited on other devices?